# Is it "the language barrier" or "language barriers"?

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentences, should I use *language barriers* or *the language barrier*?

> I feel that learning English is important for everyone since it reduces language barriers.

> It is important for everyone to learn English since it reduces language barriers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of grammar. Both sentences are grammatical.

It is a question of context.

> I feel that learning English is important for everyone [every child in Estonia] because doing so will reduce the language barrier [for Estonians].

If this is the context, “barrier” is the better choice of word because the barrier in mind is the small number of people outside Estonia who speak that language. That barrier is a single social fact.

> I feel that learning English is important for everyone [every child in Europe] because doing so will reduce the language barriers [for Europeans].

In this context, we are not thinking about a single barrier. We are considering the lack of a common global language, a multitude of incomprehensibilities, and the frequency of English as a second language. So “barriers” is the better choice.

But this is not about correct versus incorrect. It is about acceptable versus better.